# How can I analyze 3 variables with 2 objectives in R?

Tags: r, optimization, plot, multivalue

I want to conduct analysis between 3 variables and 2 objectives.
Here is the original data I have:

```
df<-structure(list(Crop = c("Vegetable A", "Vegetable B", "Maize", 
                            "Barley", "Potato", "Fruit A", "Fruit B", "Rice", "Tabacco", 
                            "Rape crop", "Faba bean", "Other beans"), `Nutrient surplus (kg/ha)` = c(495, 
                                                                                                     495, 287, 269, 330, 355, 355, 226, 194, 203, 130, 137), `Output value (yuan/ha)` = c(123450, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          123450, 26063.7180923077, 16034.4827586207, 79839.552631579, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          108500, 108500, 38518.8901345292, 107561.25, 21665.625, 19651.1045454545, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          90900), Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           "B", "B", "B")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -12L))
```

There are constraints with:

```
The total area for A+C<= 22666.67
The total area for B <= 22666.67
The total area for C <= 3333.33
unit:ha (hectare)
```

Now I want to have the **lowest** `Nutrient surplus` and **highest** `Output value`.
So it's 3 variables (`Total A`, `total B`, `total C`) and 2 objectives ( `Nutrient surplus`, `Output value`)
I'm not sure if it can be conducted by package `gMOIP`, I tried but it seems can't work with 3 variables.
Or other packages?

I expected something like this:
[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to solve a constrained optimization problem that would only need a little modification to accomplish what you want. Currently working through some errors but this will likely help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120516/r-solving-a-constrained-optimization-problem-with-nloptr-produces-error-when-te

Comment: More generally, what you'll need to do is (1) write down your objective function (maximize output, minimize surplus), (2) specify constraints on the values of the variables (they must be positive, the sum constraints you provided, etc.), (3) pick an optimization algorithm. To get the figure you see, you'll have to choose a set of binding constraints on objective function variables and calculate the optimum across those sets. That's how you get that figure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(lowest_Nutrient = min(`Nutrient surplus (kg/ha)`),
            highest_Output = max(`Output value (yuan/ha)`))
```

```
 Type  lowest_Nutrient highest_Output
  <chr>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1 A                 226        123450 
2 B                 130        123450 
3 C                 194        107561.
```

Comment: I think no. I hope I can know exactly the area value of "A,B,C" for "lowest_Nutrient, highest_Output". Is it possible? Thanks anyway!

Comment: With which the area (ha) of A,B,C respectively, then I can have the lowest nutrient surplus and highest output value?

Comment: For Type C there is only one value for nutrient surplus and output value?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explain it well in the begining. So yes, type C only has one value. And the **total** amount of nutrient surplus (**kg**) and output value (**yuan**) should depends on the components of A,B,C (**ha**) within constraints listed above. Given in the form is **kg/ha** and **yuan/ha**.

Comment: Maybe it's impossible to have real highest and lowest, but to find a balance result?

Comment: Could you show any expected output?

Comment: I updated one example, but it's two varibles with 1 objective. I have 3 varibles with 2 objectives. Not sure if it's possible?......